# Rails form_tag with image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create simple search field and in the same row search button image.

At this moment I have like this.

```
<div class="search_menu">
        <%= form_tag search_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder=> (I18n.t 'placeholder') %>  
        <%= link_to image_tag('search_button_main.png'),search_index_path, :method => 'get' %>
        <%end%>

   </div>
```

Problem: Somehow after clicking that search button it goes to controller without making search, but pushing Enter button on keyboard makes the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `image_submit_tag` is what you are looking for. Your `link_to` is just a link inside your form, it won't actually submit it.

```
<div class="search_menu">
  <%= form_tag search_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder=> (I18n.t 'placeholder') %>  
    <%= image_submit_tag 'search_button_main.png' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag